# Calculating area per range of values (classes) in raster using ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, field-calculator, spatial-analyst, area

My data consists of several points each with xy coordinates and height.

I used `spatial analyst tools -> interpolation -> natural neighbor` to get an interpolation map for the height distribution, separated in categories like 10m-20m, 20m-30m and so on. This works fine.

Now, I would like to get the area of those categories. For example, I want to see that the interpolated area in the 10m-20m range is 200m².

Comment: Use reclass in spatial analyst. You'll end up with integer raster containing values 1,2,..n zones. Convert it to polygon using raster to polygon. If output is feature class it will have shape_area field. Use summary statistics to find totals of area per zone

Comment: I converted it to a raster using 'reclassify' and then to a poly successfully - it now looks like contour lines (height) on a map. But the next step does not work. I go to 'Analysis Tools -> Statistics -> Summary Statistics' and choose the new polygon. But in 'statistic field' I only got 'FID, ID and GRIDCODE' but no 'area' field. Why is there no area field?

Comment: Just found out: You have to use 'Spatial Statistic Tools -> Utilities -> Calculate Areas' first on this poly. Then you can use 'Summary Statistics' on the new poly and select the area field.

Answer (score 1):

When calculating areas, be aware in which Coordinate Reference System (CRS) data is defined and pay attention if used tools are honoring the CRS (as opposed to project data on the fly and then, calculate areas).

Also, verify if the calculation method is aligned with your goal. For example, a projected coordinate system will yield planar areas (the area in a cartesian system), and if it is an equal area projection the result will be exact, otherwise, approximate. A geographic coordinate system will yield geodetic areas (the area based on a geoid/ellipsoid).

First, get the height classes from the raster resulted from the interpolation analysis:

- Use the [Reclassify](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) tool to convert continuous values of height into desired classes (bins): 10m-20m, 20m-30m, etc. Set the `remap` parameter equal to `RemapRange`, i.e., each value within a given range (class) will be remapped to a common value.

From here, there are two main strategies:

---

1. Calculate areas directly from the **raster**;

If CRS is in a projected coordinate system, one can count how many pixels exist in each class and multiply them by the pixel area. See [Measuring area of raster classes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/106883/measuring-area-of-raster-classes/106997#106997).

---

2. Convert the [Raster to Polygon](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polygon.htm) and then, calculate areas (for each **polygon**):

There are several tools (some of them use different methods) one can use to calculate area from polygons:

- [Field Calculator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm). Supports both planar and geodetic areas.

See the following example from Mahr (2015) - [Calculating Geodesic Areas in ArcMap with Field Calculator](http://dmahr.com/2015/07/geodesic-areas-arcmap-field-calculator/):

```
!Shape!.getArea("GEODESIC","SQUAREKILOMETERS")
```

- [Calculate Geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/calculating-area-length-and-other-geometric-properties.htm). Supports only planar area (i.e., if CRS is projected);
- [Add Geometry Attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-geometry-attributes.htm). Support both planar and geodetic areas.
- [Calculate Areas](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/calculate-areas.htm) (use it only if CRS is projected);

After calculating areas from polygons, add up (sum) their areas within each height class using the [Summary Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) tool.